# Pyspark: You cannot use dbutils within a spark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, databricks

I am trying to parallelise the execution of file copy in Databricks. Making use of multiple executors is one way. So, this is the piece of code that I wrote in pyspark.

```
def parallel_copy_execution(src_path: str, target_path: str):
  files_in_path = dbutils.fs.ls(src_path)
  file_paths_df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(files_in_path).toDF()
  file_paths_df.foreach(lambda x: dbutils.fs.cp(x.path.toString(), target_path, recurse=True))
```

I fetched all the files to copy and created a Dataframe. And when trying to run a foreach on top of the DataFrame I am getting the following error. It says that `You cannot use dbutils within a spark job`

```
You cannot use dbutils within a spark job or otherwise pickle it.
            If you need to use getArguments within a spark job, you have to get the argument before
            using it in the job. For example, if you have the following code:

              myRdd.map(lambda i: dbutils.args.getArgument("X") + str(i))

            Then you should use it this way:

              argX = dbutils.args.getArgument("X")
              myRdd.map(lambda i: argX + str(i))
```

But when I try the same in Scala. It works perfectly. The dbutils is used inside a spark job then. Attaching that piece of code as well.

```
def parallel_copy_execution(p: String, t: String): Unit = {
  dbutils.fs.ls(p).map(_.path).toDF.foreach { file =>
    dbutils.fs.cp(file(0).toString,t , recurse=true)
    println(s"cp file: $file")
  }
}
```

Is the Pyspark API's not updated to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the copies using the dbfs FUSE mount. Instead of `dbutils.fs.cp()` you just do a normal python file copy from the OS path `/dbfs/<rest-of-path>`.

So inside your `foreach` instead of

```
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/mnt/src/file.txt', 'dbfs:/mnt/tgt/file.txt')
```

Do

```
shutil.copyfile('/dbfs/mnt/src/file.txt', '/dbfs/mnt/tgt/file.txt')
```